# Pygame mouse/keyboard control condition

Tags: keyboard, pygame, mouse, conditional-statements

I have two rectangles (stripes) I want to click on the stripe move it up and down with a mouse and then move the same stripe using K_UP and K_DOWN keys. With the code I wrote I can move stripes with a mouse but the keys move both stripes simultaneously and not individually. I am only one-week coder, please help!

```
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw

pygame.init()
width, height = 800, 600
gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Koordynacja LoL")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
green = (0, 102, 0)
yellow = (255, 204, 0)

grid_color = (224, 224, 224)
k = 5


class Stripe():
    def __init__(self, color, size, pos_x, pos_y):

        self.size = size
        self.image = pygame.Surface(size)
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.rect.x = pos_x
        self.rect.y = pos_y

        self.speed = 5

    def move(self, xdir, ydir):
        self.rect.x += xdir * self.speed
        self.rect.y += ydir * self.speed

P1_len = 250
stripe1 = Stripe(green, (15, P1_len), 100, 200)

stripe_1a = Stripe(0, (15, 1000), 100, 0)
stripe_1aa = gameWindow.blit(stripe_1a.image, stripe_1a.rect)

P2_len = 110
stripe2 = Stripe(red, (15, P2_len), 200, 100)
stripe_2a = Stripe(0, (15, 1000), 200, 0)
stripe_2aa = gameWindow.blit(stripe_2a.image, stripe_2a.rect)

zielone2 = gameWindow.blit(stripe2.image, stripe2.rect)

pygame.display.update()

FPS = 15
Running = True

stripe_move = None
while Running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
        (mouseX, mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        (p1, p2, p3) = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if  stripe_1aa.collidepoint(mouseX, mouseY) and p1 == 1:
            stripe1 = Stripe(green, (15, 250), 100, mouseY-P1_len)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                stripe1.move(0, 1)
                print("lol")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                stripe1.move(0, -1)


        elif stripe_2aa.collidepoint(mouseX, mouseY) and p1 == 1:
            stripe2 = Stripe(red, (15, 110), 200,  mouseY - P2_len)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                stripe2.move(0, 1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                stripe2.move(0, -1)
                print("wut?")
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            stripe_move = None

    gameWindow.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # Draw stuff here
    """ Greedy Grid """
    for i in range(width):
        grid_x = k * i
        grid_y = k * i

        pygame.draw.line(gameWindow, grid_color, (grid_x, 0), (grid_x, height), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameWindow, grid_color, (0, grid_y), (width, grid_y), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameWindow, black, (2 * k, height - 2 * k), (width - 2 * k, height - 2 * k), 3)
        pygame.draw.line(gameWindow, black, (2 * k, height - 2 * k), (2 * k, 2 * k), 3)
        pygame.draw.aaline(gameWindow, black, (2 * k, 2 * k), (width - 2 * k, 2 * k), 3)

    pygame.draw.aaline(gameWindow, blue, (200, 115), (500, 70), True)
    gameWindow.blit(stripe1.image, stripe1.rect)
    gameWindow.blit(stripe2.image, stripe2.rect)


    # End draw stuff here
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)


pygame.quit()
quit()
enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Better post a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because that would make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: I posted the whole code

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd structure the code as follows: If the mouse is clicked and the `event.pos` collides with a stripe, assign that stripe to a variable (`selected_stripe`), and set it to `None` if the user clicks elsewhere. Also set a `scrolling` variable to `True` as long as the mousebutton is down. Outside of the event loop you can set the y-position of the selected stripe to the mouse pos. For the up and down keys you can just use the `move` method of the selected stripe.

```
selected_stripe = None
scrolling = True

while Running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                scrolling = True
                if stripe_1aa.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected_stripe = stripe1
                elif stripe_2aa.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected_stripe = stripe2
                else:
                    selected_stripe = None
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            scrolling = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if selected_stripe:
                    selected_stripe.move(0, 1)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if selected_stripe:
                    selected_stripe.move(0, -1)

    if selected_stripe and scrolling:
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        selected_stripe.rect.y = mouse_y
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Thanks a lot for teaching me this method, you rock! I have so many questions concerning this project (like how to snap stripe movement to grid) but of course I will try to use this forum as my last resort.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to add to the variable selected_stripe another rect object as stripe1 but with different y_pos and color that would move along with the stripe1(only). I tried but it doesn't work..

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. Please provide more details and the final goal. Have you tried to use a tuple or list?

Comment: With your code I can only move one rect object. I need to attach multiple rects (the same x coordinate as stripe1) and move them together.
The goal would be something like that :
http://www.stadtraum.pl/lisa3.png
It's traffic lights coordination graph

Comment: If multiple rects can be selected at the same time, you could try to use a list as the `selected_stripe`s variable and append the selected stripes to it.

Comment: I'm still not really sure how the stripes are connected, interact and how they should behave. Can the diagonal lines change the angle? And are they just connected to one of the vertical rects?

Comment: I also don't know if the tip with the list was good. Maybe you should post a new question with all requirements and an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Stripes can be moved up and down to adjust 'green wave' between them. Each row of stripes represents different intersection and the diagonal lines are stream of coordinated vehicles (angle is the static velocity you assume).